beautiful-soup: парсит только 1 страницу
Не могу понять, почему парсит только 1 страницу. При добавлении страницы переход не работает. Подскажите, где ошибка?
data = []

#page = 2

res = requests.get('https://ryvok.ru/instrumenty/shlifmashiny/')

#res = requests.get('https://ryvok.ru/instrumenty/shlifmashiny/?page={page}')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html')

elements = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__wrap')


for e in elements:

    data.append({

        'title': e.find('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__title').text.strip(),
        
        'status': e.find('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__status_color-success app-product-card__status').text.strip(),
        
        'price': e.find('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__price').text.strip().replace('\xa0','').replace(' ₽',''),
    })

Код целиком

 data = []
 page = 1 
 max_page = 1

while page <= max_page:
    res = requests.get('https://ryvok.ru/instrumenty/shlifmashiny/?page={page}')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html')


    elements = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__wrap')


    for e in elements:
        data.append({
            'title': e.find('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__title').text.strip(),
        
            'status': e.find('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__status_color-success app-product-card__status').text.strip(),
        
            'price': e.find('div', class_ = 'app-product-card__price').text.strip().replace('\xa0','').replace(' ₽',''),
        })
        
    pagination = soup.find('div', class_ = 'ui-pagination__numbers')

    pages = [int(p.text.strip()) for p in pagination.find_all('div', class_ = 'ui-pagination__number')]
    
    int_pages = []
    for p in pages:
        try:
            n = int(p)
            int_pages.append(n)
        except:
            continue
            

    max_page = max(int_pages)
    
    page += 1
    
    print(page, max_page)


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 22

while True:
    print(page)
    url = f'https://ryvok.ru/instrumenty/shlifmashiny/?page={page}&sort=6&sort_order=0'
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    # elements = soup(class_='app-product-card__wrap')
    elements = soup.select('.app-product-card__wrap')
    ...
    *_, pagination = soup.select_one('.ui-pagination__numbers').stripped_strings
    if page == int(pagination):
        break
    page += 1

# 22
# 23
# 24


Спасибо большое за ответ. Код работает
